# AudioSessionGetProperty ('tfac') failed with error: 'tahw'"

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudiosession

I am getting following  error when play video from url:-

"[0x3c8eb18c] Received corrupt data. Property list is  NULL
2014-03-06 16:26:30.980[2034:60b] 16:26:30.980 ERROR:     [0x3c8eb18c] AVAudioSessionUtilities.h:88: GetProperty_DefaultToZero: AudioSessionGetProperty ('tfac') failed with error: 'tahw'".

I get this error when post video from app to server and after uploading  I get the url and play in mpmovieplayercontroller. but if  I close the app and run that video it works fine.

If any person knows about it plz let me know.
 thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and was stumped for quite a while. In the end I found that my `AVAudioSession` was configured for recording instead of playback. Setting it to playback before loading the video solved my problem. Hope this helps!

```
// Configure audio session
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

Comment: I later discovered that setting the category like this: `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:nil];` worked better when switching categories often.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import the Audio Tool box framework to your App. 
In you .h file add the below line
i.e.
`#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`

Now in your .m file in viewDidLaod() add the below code

```
  UInt32 allowMixing = true;
        AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);

  [self.moviePlayer setUseApplicationAudioSession:NO];
```